# Using Arrays to store Cell Values between Procedures VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a flexible program where I can reference the array values from the **CaseManagerValues** and use them in the **CalculateM2Balances & CalculateM1Balances** rather than manually declaring variables such as EmmaBalance at the beginning.

My system currently copies and pastes list of names from Dataset workbook into ThisWorkbook, stores these values into an array, outputs array values into Summary1 worksheet and calculates the account balances for each name using a SUMIF based on the Balance column in the Dataset workbook.

The code beneath represents 4 procedures:

1. **CopyAndPaste**: Opens Dataset workbook, copies names from column H and pastes into column A of SampleDoc of this workbook. Then removes duplicates so that values are unique.
2. **CaseManagerValues**: Takes unique name values from SampleDoc worksheet and stores them into array, CaseManagers(). Case Managers() are outputted to Summary1 spreadsheet.
3. **CalculateM2Balances & CalculateM1Balances**: (2 separate but similar procedures) the first opens a file from 2 months ago, the other opens a file from 1 month ago. In both procedures, it looks for a managers name i.e. Emma and finds the total sum (using SUMIF) her account balance from the Dataset workbook. It then adds these figures in the cell beside Emma's name. (most of these procedures are related to folders etc. so a lot of the dates and columns might seem a bit confusing)

**1.**

```
'This procedure takes the name of all the case managers from the 1M Dataset worksheet _
'and lists them in the SampleDoc worksheet
Sub CopyAndPasteTest()

'declaring variables for files & their directories
Dim pStr As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim dirFile As String

'declaring ranges for 0 & blank
'these appear in the case manager column and are not used
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

'specifiying the file locations
pStr = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Monthly Files\2021\01. January 2021\"
strFile = "Dataset" & "*"
dirFile = Dir(pStr & strFile)

'checking if the file exists in the directory specified
'message box will appear if it does not
If Len(dirFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File does not exist!"
Else

'opens workbook if it does exist
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(pStr & dirFile)
End If

'setting Dataset Case Manager column as the source of names
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks(dirFile).Worksheets("HET DataSet").Columns("H")
'setting SampleDoc of this workbook as the intended destination
Set targetColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleDoc").Columns("A")

'copy & paste case managers from dataset into monthly reporting tool
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

'close dataset wb
ActiveWorkbook.Close
    

End Sub
```

**2.**

```
'This procedure adds Case Manager heading to A2 & adds each unique CM beneath
Sub CaseManagerValues()

    'Add Case Manager as heading
    Sheets("Summary1").Cells(2, 1).Value = "Case Manager"

    'declaring case managers as array; size & i as integers
    Dim CaseManagers() As String, size As Integer, i As Integer
    
    'counts how many rows in the column
    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("SampleDoc").Columns(1))
    
    'redimming allows flexibility with the arrays
    ReDim CaseManagers(size)

    'loop will return each case manager from the SampleDoc
    For i = 1 To size - 1
    
        CaseManagers(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SampleDoc").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary1").Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = CaseManagers(i)
        
    Next i
    

End Sub
```

**3.**

```
'Code to calculate balances for 2 months ago
Sub CalculateM2Balances()

'Declaring location of file from 2 months ago
Dim M2_Folder As String
Dim M2_File As String
Dim rt As String

'Declaring the year that it was 2 months ago
Dim Year_2M As Integer

'Declaring the month that it was 2 months ago
Dim Month_2M As String

'Declaring strings to represent month 1 & 2 months ago
Dim MonthChar_2 As String

'Declaring account balances for each case manager
'just declaring 1 for sake of simplicity
Dim EmmaBalance As Long


'Declaring columns with Account Balance & Case Manager
Dim CaseColumnL As String
Dim CaseColumnN As Integer

'Declaring year value from 2 months ago
'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago
Year_2M = Format(Date - 57, "YYYY")

'Declaring month value 2 months ago
'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago
Month_2M = Format(Date - 57, "MM")

'This translates the current month from number to character format
MonthChar_2 = MonthName(Month_2M, False)

'referencing folder locations for files from 2 months ago
rt = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Monthly Files\"
M2_Folder = Year_2M & "\" & Month_2M & ". " & MonthChar_2 & " " & Year_2M & "\" & "Dataset*"
M2_File = rt & M2_Folder

'opens the workbook
Workbooks.Open M2_File

'Defining column number based on which column Case Manager is located in the Dataset worksheet
CaseColumnN = Range("1:1").Cells.Find("Case Manager").Column
BalanceColumnN = Range("1:1").Cells.Find("AS400 Account Balance").Column

'Defining column letter based on which column Case Manager is located_
'in the Dataset worksheet i.e. Column 8 = H
'This is important when referencing your ranges at the SUMIF stage
CaseColumnL = Split(Cells(1, CaseColumnN).Address, "$")(1)
BalanceColumnL = Split(Cells(1, BalanceColumnN).Address, "$")(1)


'SumIf statements to determine the total account balance of each case manager based on dataset
'Referencing the column headers - searching for Case Manager & Account balance in the dataset_
'workbook and returning values based on this
EmmaBalance = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("HET DataSet"). _
Range(CaseColumnL & ":" & CaseColumnL), "Emma", Worksheets("HET DataSet"). _
Range(BalanceColumnL & ":" & BalanceColumnL))


'closes the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'finding 'Account Balance' in Row 1, naming it c
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("1:1")
        Set c = .Find("Account Balance", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
        'finding 'Emma' in column A, calling it d
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set d = .Find("Emma", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
    If d Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Emma not found!"
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary1").Cells(d.Row, c.Column).Value = EmmaBalance


End Sub




'Code to calculate balances for month 1
Sub CalculateM1Balances()

'Declaring location of January files
Dim M1_Folder As String
Dim M1_File As String
Dim rt As String

'Declaring the years that it was 1 month ago
Dim Year_1M As Integer

'Declaring the months that it was 1 month ago
Dim Month_1M As String

'Declaring strings to represent month 1 month ago
Dim MonthChar_1 As String

'Declaring account balances for each case manager
Dim EmmaBalance As Long

'Declaring columns with Account Balance & Case Manager
Dim CaseColumnL As String
Dim CaseColumnN As Integer

'Declaring year value of 1 month ago
'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
Year_1M = Format(Date - 27, "YYYY")

'Declaring month value of 1 month ago
'This is important to compare datasets from last month
Month_1M = Format(Date - 27, "MM")

'This translates the current month from number to character format
MonthChar_1 = MonthName(Month_1M, False)

'referencing folder locations for files from 1 month ago
rt = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Monthly Files\"
M1_Folder = Year_1M & "\" & Month_1M & ". " & MonthChar_1 & " " & Year_1M & "\" & "Dataset*"
M1_File = rt & M1_Folder

'opens the workbook before
Workbooks.Open M1_File

'Defining column number based on which column Case Manager is located in the Dataset worksheet
CaseColumnN = Range("1:1").Cells.Find("Case Manager").Column
BalanceColumnN = Range("1:1").Cells.Find("AS400 Account Balance").Column

'Defining column letter based on which column Case Manager is located_
'in the Dataset worksheet i.e. Column 8 = H
'This is important when referencing your ranges at the SUMIF stage
CaseColumnL = Split(Cells(1, CaseColumnN).Address, "$")(1)
BalanceColumnL = Split(Cells(1, BalanceColumnN).Address, "$")(1)


'SumIf statements to determine the total account balance of each case manager based on dataset
'Referencing the column headers - searching for Case Manager & Account balance in the dataset_
'workbook and returning values based on this
EmmaBalance = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("HET DataSet"). _
Range(CaseColumnL & ":" & CaseColumnL), "Emma", Worksheets("HET DataSet"). _
Range(BalanceColumnL & ":" & BalanceColumnL))



'closes the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'finding 'Account Balance' in Row 1, naming it c
    With Workbooks("Monthly Reporting Tool.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("1:1")
        Set c = .Find("Account Balance", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
        'finding 'Emma' in column A, calling it d
    With Workbooks("Monthly Reporting Tool.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set d = .Find("Emma", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
    If d Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Emma not found!"
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary1").Cells(d.Row, c.Column + 1).Value = EmmaBalance


End Sub
```

My issue is that in 3, these values are pre-determined which does not allow for any flexibility. For example, I have declared EmmaBalance as String but she may be removed in next month's file. Similarly, if a new manager is added to the system (i.e. Joseph), then I would need to hard code this in. I've declared these values in the array in **CaseManagerValues** but am not sure how to interlink them.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to implement Excel [pivot tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) by hand. If you must, put the names of the managers in one column, and a [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) in the next column. The `sumif` may refer to other files.

Comment: That's how it's currently laid out - Names are in column A, SumIf for 2 months is in column B, SumIf for 1 month is in column C. The issue is that I'm struggling to take the values stored in part 2 and transfer them to part 3 - then use these values in the SumIfs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle the entire calculation in memory, and then move all of the values over to the summary sheet when finished. I'll post my solution below. I took some shortcuts to make it manageable (for example, instead of opening different workbooks, I just created different worksheets in the same workbook. It made it easier to test. You'll have to adapt your code to suit).

It still follows a general 3 step approach. First, it creates a dictionary with unique case workers names as the key. The value for each entry is a 2 element array that is initialized to 0 and 0, representing Month1 and Month2 values, respectively.

Next, it accesses the values from the Month1 worksheet and adds them to the corresponding entry in the dictionary. If the value is on the spreadsheet but not in the dictionary, it will be ignored. This allows your code to be more dynamic (no more hardcoded `EmmaBalance` variable names). Repeat the process for Month2.

Finally, it populates the data into the summary sheet directly from the dictionary.

You'll have to update the code to match your workbook/worksheet names, and your column references. It should be straightforward to follow, but right back if you have questions.

```
Sub PopulateSummary()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim oDict As Object
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("Summary")
    currentRow = 1
    
    Set oDict = CalculateBalances()
    
    For Each itm In oDict.keys
        'Column A of summary has case manager name
        sht.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = itm
        
        'Column B of summary has M1 value
        sht.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = oDict(itm)(0)
        
        'Column C of summary has M2 value
        sht.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = oDict(itm)(1)
        
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Next itm
    
End Sub

Private Function CalculateBalances() As Object
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim shtM1 As Worksheet
    Dim shtM2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim keyValue As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    'Get the Unique Case Managers dictionary
    'This will contain each unique case manager as
    'the key, and a 2 element array with M1 and M2 balances,
    'initialized to 0, 0
    Set oDict = GetUniqueCaseManagers
    
    'Sheet with M1 balances
    Set shtM1 = Worksheets("Month1")
    
    'Sheet with M2 balances
    Set shtM2 = Worksheets("Month2")
    
    'Loop over each data value in the Month(n) worksheets,
    'If the Case Manager is in the dictionary, then add the
    'totals. If not, I'm just ignoring it (maybe a case manager
    'left. You can include custom logic here if you want)
    lRow = shtM1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        keyValue = shtM1.Cells(i, "A").Value
        
        If oDict.exists(keyValue) Then
            arr = oDict(keyValue)
            
            'Assuming that the values being summed are in column B
            'Update as necessary
            arr(0) = arr(0) + shtM1.Cells(i, "B").Value
            
            oDict(keyValue) = arr
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Repeat for M2
    lRow = shtM2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        keyValue = shtM2.Cells(i, "A").Value
        
        If oDict.exists(keyValue) Then
            arr = oDict(keyValue)
            
            'Assuming that the values being summed are in column B
            'Update as necessary
            arr(1) = arr(1) + shtM2.Cells(i, "B").Value
            
            oDict(keyValue) = arr
        End If
    Next i
    
    Set CalculateBalances = oDict
End Function


Private Function GetUniqueCaseManagers() As Object
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim shtManagers As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim keyValue As String
    
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Point to the sheet with the case managers
    Set shtManagers = Worksheets("CaseManagers")
    
    'Last Row of Column H to get case managers
    lRow = shtManagers.Cells(shtManagers.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        keyValue = shtManagers.Cells(i, "H").Value
        Dim aTemp(0 To 1) As Double
        
        aTemp(0) = 0
        aTemp(1) = 0
        
        If Not oDict.exists(keyValue) Then
            oDict.Add keyValue, aTemp
        End If
    Next i

    Set GetUniqueCaseManagers = oDict
End Function
```